# nautilus: no modification, access dates for folder

Tags: nautilus, directory, file-properties

when looking folder properties I dont see properties like Modification date or accessed date.
[screenshot (folder properties on right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wsxmh.png)

I am on ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

Okay, my bad.

The image on the right appears to refer to an inode type as opposed to an html type.

It appears that the basic properties cannot be resolved with an inode type.

Comment: how to resolve this?